# JVM -ea parameter ignored in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, assert

I'm working on a Scala project in IntelliJ. I'm trying to use `Predef.assert`.

Given the following code :

```
test("TEST"){
    try{
        Predef.assert(0 == 1,"test")
    }
    catch{
        case e :AssertionError => println("Catch")
    }
    println("End")
}
```

I create a **configuration** in IntelliJ with the VM option : `-ea`

I expect to have `Catch`and `End`written in the console, but it outputs only `End`

The assertion is ignored, even if I enable it in the VM options of the current configuration of IntelliJ. Is there anyone who has experienced this ?

I can even see in the IntelliJ console that the parameter has been added :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe" -ea "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.5\lib ...
```

How do I enable the assertions properly ?

Comment: My assertions are triggered when debugging in IntelliJ even without any explicit option to enable them. I think perhaps your problem is not related to -ea option at all.

Comment: Could you make sure those assertions are from `Predef` and not Scalatest's ?

Comment: I hope I am not talking about something completely different. I use normal assertions in my code (not only test) frequently and I never had any issues with them not triggering. When you place an assert in your code and debug it, does it work?

Comment: No, the line is ignored, the debugger considers it doesn't contain any executable statement, so it's skipped. I know those assertions are normally elided, and the `-ea` option is precisely supposed to activate them, but it doesn't work and I can't understand why

Comment: @ArthurAttout please share [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder, Isn't the code I've given short enough ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout it's not a complete example.

Comment: @CrazyCoder does the edit fulfill those requirements ? Otherwise, I don't really understand what you mean. This is the only code I run, and the configuration seems pretty clear and minimal to me.

Comment: @ArthurAttout share the zipped project with all the dependencies and the run configurations so that others can download, open it and reproduce the issue, fiddle with it to find what's wrong and help you solve this issue. Right now it's a bit of the extra work to set up the same project with the same dependencies, JDK, run configuration, etc.

Comment: Okay, myself to blame, you can see my answer. Although, I think this question falls into the questions that 'were caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.'. Actually don't know if I should delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after being confronted to the fact that it works with a new project (only myself to blame here, always start from scratch, as per [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) I started digging, and the fact is, a parameter was still laying in the file `.idea/scala_compiler`

I had to remove

```
<parameter value="-Xdisable-assertions" />
```

Which obviously overtook the VM parameters.

Comment: Great to hear that you could resolve your problem. Could you please accept your own answer, so the question is marked accordingly.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of how SO works, however there is always a 48h delay before I can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of starting IntelliJ itself with the VM option, you have to configure it to run your program with the appropriate options.

Open the run configuration of your project and add the options as shown in the following Screenshots:

[image: Open Run Configurations]

[image: Set VM options parameter]

Comment: This is what I have done. The option is in the VM options field, but the code I've shown in my question still ignores the assertion. The line I've posted under is only the output in the IntelliJ console, that confirms the option has properly been added.